# How to rename a column of a Pandas dataframes list with different name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have three dataframes with a column that has the same name ("col_0") in all three dfs:

```
>>> df_a

    Date        col_0
0   1/22/2020   4.0
1   1/23/2020   1.2

>>> df_b

    Date        col_0
0   1/22/2020   4.1
1   1/23/2020   1.3

>>> df_c

    Date        col_0
0   1/22/2020   4.2
1   1/23/2020   1.5
```

I want to rename each column in each df with different name in a list of names `new = ["A","B","C"]` using a loop but I was unable to do so. I already tried using a comprehension list to name each column but I get 9 dataframes (three of each dataframes with the new names from the new list).

```
>>> [i.rename(columns={'col_0':j}) i for i in [df_a,df_b,df_c] for j in ["A","B","C"]]
```

But the output I really need:

```
>>> df_a

    Date        A
0   1/22/2020   4.0
1   1/23/2020   1.2

>>> df_b

    Date        B
0   1/22/2020   4.1
1   1/23/2020   1.3

>>> df_c

    Date        C
0   1/22/2020   4.2
1   1/23/2020   1.5
```

Any ideas how I can get that output. First of all, Thanks.

Comment: Simply use `zip` for elementwise looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df_a,df_b,df_c=[i.rename(columns={'col_0':j}) for i, j in zip([df_a,df_b,df_c],["A","B","C"])]
df_a
Out[565]: 
        Date    A
0  1/22/2020  4.0
1  1/23/2020  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nested loops:

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

for column in columns:
    for df in dfs:
        df.rename(columns={'col_0': column})
```